# Rails4 has_many :through then how to get the value in new.html.erb

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I use Rails4.2.8, Ruby2.5.0.

I had the multilevel relation in `questions` , `classifies`, `tags` , tables relations is like this :[image]

**My models :**

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggables,:dependent => :destroy, inverse_of: :question
  has_many :tags, through: :taggables, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :classify
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :taggables
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggables, :dependent => :destroy,inverse_of: :question
  has_many :questions, through: :taggables, :dependent => :destroy,inverse_of: :question
  belongs_to :classify
end

class Classify < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions, :dependent => :destroy, inverse_of: :classify
  has_many :tags, :dependent => :destroy, inverse_of: :classify
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags
end

class Taggable < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :tag
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :question
end
```

**My dbs:**

```
class CreateQuestions < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :questions do |t|
          t.string :title
          t.text :content
          t.integer :classify_id
          t.timestamps
        end
      end
    end

class CreateTags < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :tags do |t|
          t.string :name
          t.text :content
          t.integer :classify_id
          t.timestamps
        end
      end
    end


class CreateClassifies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :classifies do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :content
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateTaggables < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :taggables do |t|
      t.integer :question_id
      t.integer :tag_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**My controllers:**

```
questions_controller.rb
def new
    @question = Question.new
    @question.taggables.build
    @question.tags.build
  end



classifies_controller.rb
def new
    @classify = Classify.new
    @classify.questions.build
    @classify.tags.build
  end


tags_controller.rb
def new
    @tag = Tag.new
    @tag.taggables.build
    @tag.questions.build
  end
```

**My `questions/new.html.erb`**

```
    <%= form_for(@question) do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :classify, "Classify and Tags" %><br>
        <div class="input-group tags" >
          <div class="tags_select">
            <%= f.select :classify_id, Classify.all.collect { |c| [c.name, c.id]},{}, class: "form-control" %>   ##I can get the classify_id in questions 
          </div>
          <div class="tags_input col-md-12">
            <%= f.text_field :tag, class: "",multiple:"multiple",placeholder: "Please input the tags" %> 
**## There how can I get the input tags , and record the id and name in `tags table` ,  `taggables table`? Then how can I show the tags name in the question `show.html.erb`?**
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    <% end %>
```

What I want is how to record the input tags id and name in `tags table` ,  `taggables table`,Then how can I show the tags name in the question `show.html.erb`?

Thansk so much for your help .

Comment: There does not appear to be a question here.

Comment: So how could I write the codes ,could you tell me ? This problem bothers me for a few days. Thanks @Marlin Pierce.

Comment: When I input the tags , the `tags table `  cann't record the tag name. I know there is something wrong in the codes , but I donn't how to fix it . Could you help me ? @Marlin Pierce. Thanks a lot .

Comment: The data is recorded in the `create` or `update` action in the controller.  You only showed us the `new` action.

Comment: Thanks, I got it.